# Implementation of Video.js in Nextjs and Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js13

I have implemented video.js library in my project and its working successfully also. But when i am trying to fetch and load more videos i.e. upto 120 to 140 videos then my app is getting crashed. So i am not getting any solution how to solve or prevent my web app from crashing.

This is my code. What should i do to prevent my web app from crashing.

```
const LukPlayer = memo((props) => {
    const videoRef = useRef(null)
    const playerRef = useRef(null)
    const observerRef = useRef(null)
    const { options, onReady, data, commentFlag, flag } = props

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const [playing, setCurrentPlaying] = useState([])
    const [sources, setSources] = useState([])

    const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.user)

    useEffect(() => {
      if (
        options?.sources !== sources &&
        !options?.sources[0]?.src?.includes('undefined')
      ) {
        setSources(options?.sources)
      }
    }, [options?.sources])

    // check if you are on client side
    const isClient = typeof window !== 'undefined'

    function check_iOS() {
      return (
        [
          'iPad Simulator',
          'iPhone Simulator',
          'iPod Simulator',
          'iPad',
          'iPhone',
          'iPod',
        ].includes(navigator.platform) ||
        // iPad on iOS 13 detection
        /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent)
      )
    }

    let ios = isClient ? check_iOS() : ''

    // Add event listener for spacebar key press
    useEffect(() => {
      const handleKeyPress = async (event) => {
        if (event.code === 'Space') {
          event.preventDefault()
          const player = playerRef.current
          if (player) {
            if (player?.paused()) {
              // add support for ios non user interaction policy
              // if (!ios) {
              await player?.play()
              // }
              //end ios support
            } else {
              // if (!ios) {
              player?.pause()
              // }
            }
          }
        }
      }

      // check if the video element is in view
      const checkIfVideoInView = (entries) => {
        entries?.forEach((entry) => {
          if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            // if the video is in view, attach keydown event listener to play/pause
            document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress)
          } else {
            // if the video is not in view, remove keydown event listener
            document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress)
          }
        })
      }
      checkIfVideoInView()

      return () => {
        document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress)
        observerRef.current.disconnect()
      }
    }, [commentFlag, flag === 'create' && options, videoRef])

    useEffect(() => {
      // Make sure Video.js player is only initialized once
      if (!playerRef.current) {
        // The Video.js player needs to be _inside_ the component el for React 18 Strict Mode.
        const videoElement = document.createElement('video-js')

        videoElement?.classList.add('vjs-big-play-centered')
        videoRef?.current.appendChild(videoElement)

        let opt =
          options?.sources !== sources &&
          !options?.sources[0]?.src?.includes('undefined') &&
          options

        const player = videojs(videoElement, opt, () => {
          onReady && onReady(player)
        })
        playerRef.current = player

        // Event listener for the 'ended' event
        player.on('ended', () => {
          onVideoEnd()
        })

        // You could update an existing player in the `else` block here
        // on prop change, for example:
      } else {
        const player = playerRef?.current

        player?.autoplay(options.autoplay)
        if (sources?.length > 0) {
          player?.src(sources)
        }

        player.name_ = data
      }

      // create an observer and observe the element
      const videoNode = videoRef.current

      const observerOptions = {
        root: null,
        rootMargin: '0px',
        threshold: 0.5,
      }
      const player = playerRef.current

      observerRef.current = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
        entries.forEach(async (entry) => {
          if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            // add support for ios non user interaction policy
            // if (!ios) {
            await player?.play()
            // }
            //end ios support
            player.name_ = data
            // set into state the currently playing video
            setCurrentPlaying(player.name_)
          } else {
            // if (!ios) {
            player?.pause()
            // }
          }
        })
      }, observerOptions)
      observerRef.current.observe(videoNode)

      return () => {
        playerRef.current?.dispose()
        playerRef.current = null
        observerRef.current.disconnect()
      }
    }, [commentFlag, flag === 'create' && options, playerRef])

    const view = async (e) => {
      if (user?.token) {
        await dispatch(viewVideo(e))
      }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(setPlaying(playing))
      if (playing?.id) {
        view(playing)
      }
    }, [playing?.id])

    return (
      <div data-vjs-player>
        <div className={style.luk_player_wrapper} ref={videoRef} />
      </div>
    )
})

export default LukPlayer
```